Why does a Http Post Request get Queued in IIS Occasionally
I have an ASP.NET Core web application hosted in IIS. This is meant to service clients with certain inventory and online booking.
The requests come from a connector application (also designed in .NET Core) hosted separately, which in turn is communicated by third parties.
The connector sends requests using HttpRequest class, and a timeout of 20 seconds is also set there.The requests are using the POST verb.
Now a weird problem has started.
Occasionally (perhaps 1 or 2 in a day) a booking request would get queued up for minutes and the server stops servicing until this request is killed. During the time, CPU and Memory utilization are found normal. Somebody should keep a watch on the IIS console for such queues, otherwise it stops the show. Wondering what could be the reason for it and how to mitigate the issue !
Can anybody show some light on this?
Much appreciated. Thanks

Very likely you have a deadlock bug in the code. Without analyzing further no one here can give you the answer. Since it is not feasible to release your code for others to review publicly, you'd better hire an experienced consultant to help or open a support case via https://support.microsoft.com

There's no information in the question. I say that as someone that works in air tickets and knows about bookings and very high traffic. Perhaps there's a bug that causes deadlocks or infinite loops? The only thing one can say is that ASP.NET Core 3.1 went out of support several years ago and even .NET 6, the next LTS version, is reaching EOL in November. .NET 6 and 8 had significant performance improvements, especially around allocations, which could easily matter here.

Add proper logging, metrics, tracing to your code and check what happens when that request seems to hand. I've seen infinite loops cause blocks because of a single unexpected infinite recursion in a single infrequent GDS booking. In 64-bits tail recursion optimizations mean that if your CreatePNR(string gds=null) constructor ends with a Create() due to a typo (notice the default parameter value), you get an infinite recursion that never causes stack overflow. Same with constructors

the server stops servicing until this request is killed. that's not how IIS works. Each request is served by a different thread. The only way to get a frozen server in normal circumstances would be if all CPU cores were busy eg in infinite loops. IIS itself would notice this and recycle the app pool after a while unless someone turned this precaution off, thus causing the server to remain stuck. That situation would be obvious from the CPU metrics

Bad coding and blocking on a singleton resource is another thing that could cause long blocks or even deadlocks, if the application code is written in such a way that one request locks one singleton resource in the beginning and then tries to lock another near the end, while another does this in reverse. That's why web apps should not use singleton resources and avoid blocking operations as much as possible

@PanagiotisKanavos There is a singleton which is locked by lock() block. From your assumption, it could be a possible issue. In that case, what do you suggest to do with that

Don't lock. As for what to do, without any code one can only guess. Perhaps you're caching lookup data, perhaps not. Reading lookup data doesn't require locks if you just swap the existing eg Dictionary with a new one. ASP.NET Core already has thread-safe caching mechanisms. Even if you can't use these, you can use a ConcurrentDictionary
